# Which adapter choose?

Tags: android, cursor, android-arrayadapter, simplecursoradapter, listadapter

I have two methods which read the same data from `database`, the first returns `Cursor` and the second returns `List` of objects.Now I show my items in activity using `SimpleCursorAdapter` and the first method, byt I can also use the second method and appropriate adapter.
Which of these two ways is beter to use and in the second way which adapter I should use?

P.S sorry for poor english

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely go with `SimpleCursorAdapter`. If possible, always use `Cursor` if your data comes from `database`, you save memory by not creating `List` of objects. Creating objects in Java is expensive with regards to time and memory consumption and you have to bear in mind you are on mobile platform with limited resources. If you are using `List` of objects for your `ListView` than use custom adapter extending from `ArrayAdapter`.

It's not always straightforward to use `Cursor` although your data comes from `database`. Let's say you store places in the `database` defined by its name and location and you want to display them in a `ListView` sorted by distance from current location. It makes it difficult to execute a query which returns sorted results unless you don't store relative distance in additional column. But you can get `Cursor` convert it to `List` of objects and sort this collection before sending it to your `ListView`.

Comment: Yes, I use ListView and setListAdapter(adapterName), my first method simply returns the cursor that executes the select query, and second method fills the list of items running through cursor which first nwthod returns, I can use both of these methods and appropiate adapters, as I understand it is better to use Cursror ?

Comment: Yes, use `SimpleCursorAdapter`, it is created exactly for this scenario and such to display data in `ListView` from `database`.